# Limit the output to only two items in each div tag using foreach loop in Razor

Tags: c#, html, razor, foreach-loop-container

I want only two items to display in the div tag. So the first div tag would display two items or products and then I would add another div tag to show the next two. I can't change the db.Query because I need the data from that specific department. Is there a way to do this? Should I use something other than the foreach loop? Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if what I want is confusing. Thank you!

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("Kudler Internet");
    var products = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Inventory  WHERE Department='Bakery'");

}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Shopping Online - Kudler Fine Foods</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" media="screen" title="html5doctor.com Reset Stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/960.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/kudler.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js" >

</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="internet">

<header class="wrapper">
  <div class="container_16 logo">
    <p>Kudler Fine Foods</p>
  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>

</header>

<nav class="container_16 navigation">


        <ul>
                 <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="catalog.html">ONLINE SHOPPING</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a>Bakery</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a>Meat &amp; Seafood</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a>Produce</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a>Cheese &amp; Dairy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a>Wine</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
</li>

                <li>
                    <a>CART</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>ABOUT</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>NEWS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>LOCATIONS</a>
                </li>
  </ul>
        <hr />
</nav>

<section class="container_16">
<div id="slideshow"> 
        <img src="images/ph_940_300.gif" alt="Placeholder image"  title="Placeholder Image" /> 
  </div>

  <nav class="navigation secondarynav">

      <hr />
    </nav>

<div id="article" class="container_16">



<div class="grid_6">
    @foreach (var img in products){
            <img src="images/ph_244_188.gif" alt="placeholder image" width="185" height="160" style="float:left; margin-right:30px; padding-bottom:10px;" title ="Placeholder Image" />
                                                                                                                                                                              }
</div>

        <div class="grid_6 content border_left">
            @foreach (var p in products ) 
            {

            <h1> @p.InventoryItem</h1>
            <p> @p.Price</p>
          <p>@p.Units  </p>
                     <br/>}
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Use a simple for loop that increases by 2 each loop. Be sure to check each element exists before trying to print it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the incrementing value of a `for` loop for this.  Something like this:

```
<div class="grid_6 content border_left">
@for (var i = 0; i < products.Count(); i++)
{
    <h1>@products[i].InventoryItem</h1>
    <p>@products[i].Price</p>
    <p>@products[i].Units</p>
    <br/>
    @if (i % 2 == 1)
    {
        </div>
        <div class="grid_6 content border_left">
    }
}
</div>
```

This should output the `h1` and `p` elements as normal, and every 2nd iteration of the loop also output a closing and reopening of the `div` element.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Linq grouping to combine the items into groups of 2.  Something like this:

```
@foreach (var grp in products
    .Select((index, item) => { index = index, item = item }))
    .GroupBy(item => item.index / 2))
{
    <div class="grid_6 content border_left">
        @foreach (var p in grp)
        {
            <h1> @p.item.InventoryItem</h1>
            <p> @p.item.Price</p>
            <p> @p.item.Units </p>
            <br/>
        }
    </div>
}
```